# How to clean up temporary file after response in JAX-RS REST Service?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am returning a temporary file from my JAX-RS REST Service like below:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFile() {
  File file = ... // create a temporary file
  return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
      .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" ) //optional
      .build();
}
```

What is the correct way of removing this temporary file after the response has been processed? Is the JAX-RS implementation (like Jersey) supposed to do this automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an instance of [`StreamingOutput`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html) that copies the content of the source file to the client output and eventually deletes the file.

```java
final Path path = getTheFile().toPath();
final StreamingOutput output = o -> {
    final long copied = Files.copy(path, o);
    final boolean deleted = Files.deleteIfExists(path);
};
return Response.ok(output).build();
```

```java
final File file = getTheFile();
return Response.ok((StreamingOutput) output -> {
        final long copied = Files.copy(file.toPath(), output);
        final boolean deleted = file.delete();
    }).build();
```

Comment: Please provide a reason as to why you think this will answer the question. Your answer is very incomplete.

Comment: Did you mean **`StreamingOutput`** (javax.ws.rs.core) instead of **`StreamingResult`**?

Comment: @WesFoster - what's wrong with the answer?  Literally copy & pasting it into my "public Response getThing()" method body solved my problem.  (Though perhaps this "StreamingResult" typo that was fixed circa December 2019 blocked you...)

Answer (score 1):

The example on https://dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-streaming-response looks more helpful than the brief reply from Jin Kwon.

Here is an example:

```
public Response getDocumentForMachine(@PathParam("custno") String custno, @PathParam("machineno") String machineno,
        @PathParam("documentno") String documentno, @QueryParam("language") @DefaultValue("de") String language)
        throws Exception {
    log.info(String.format("Get document. mnr=%s, docno=%s, lang=%s", machineno, documentno, language));

    File file = new DocFileHelper(request).getDocumentForMachine(machineno, documentno, language);
    if (file == null) {
        log.error("File not found");
        return Response .status(404)
                        .build();
    }

    StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            log.info("Stream file: " + file);
            try (FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                int len = 0;
                while ((len = inp.read(buff)) >= 0) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, len);
                }
                out.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.log(Level.ERROR, "Stream file failed", e);
                throw new IOException("Stream error: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                log.info("Remove stream file: " + file);
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    };

    return Response .ok(stream)
                    .build();
}
```